# Recursion With Two Identical Parameters

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a recursive method which outputs the smallest String in a binary search tree that has its reverse in the tree but I feel the way I accomplished this task was poorly done.

I have a driver method that passes the root variable **twice** to the recursive overloaded method. I feel like this is not only confusing, but considered poor practice. The reason I passed it twice was to keep track of the original root variable so I can pass it into a search method that requires it. Is there an alternative way to do this or am I stuck with it?

Relevant code:

```
    public String smallRev() {
        return smallRev(root,root); // <--- Bad practice?
    }

    private static String smallRev(StringNode temproot, StringNode root) {
        String result;
        if (temproot == null) {
            result = "";
        } else if (search(root, revString(temproot.getString()))) { //<-- Used here
            result = temproot.getString();
        } else {
            String left = smallRev(temproot.getLeft(),root); // <-- Here
            String right = smallRev(temproot.getRight(),root); // <-- & Here
            if (!left.equals("")) {
                result = left;
            } else {
                result = right;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You can just copy your root variable inside your method into a temp variable. No need to pass it twice.

Comment: @svz Ah... Duh. That's embarrassing. Thank you. :)

Comment: @svz Actually, I don't think that will work since I forgot it recursively searches both the left and right nodes in the else statement. The real root variable needs to be passed for the search statement.